# Is custom antialiasing possible in DirectX11?

Tags: 3d, directx, directx-11, antialiasing

I want to make "comparison" beetween antialiasing algorithms and i was looking for suitable 3D Api. I choosed DX 11, because I'm absolutely newbie in practical 3D programming and i want to learn some. The question is: Will DX11 allow me to implement custom antialiasing algorithms like SSAA, MSAA, FXAA, TXAA etc. or is it all built-in and forbidden?

Comment: You can implement any algorithm you want with DX11, MSAA is the only thing which is handled by the interface itself, the others have to made by you. But beware anti-aliasing algorithms tend to be very complex and difficult (except SSAA) and may not the best entry in learning 3D programming.

Comment: Am i right that AA algorithms which i mentioned (except MSAA) are just postprocesses? What about MSAA? Even if it's handled by interface, is something blocking me to implement it by myself?

Comment: MSAA and SSAA are done while rendering, the others are postprocessing of image data. I think you can implement MSAA as well, but of course not at the performance of hardware MSAA.

Comment: Thank you very much for answers!